# How to share a interface over multiple assemblies

Tags: c#, windows, forms, plugins

Hello 
I have a main app that is going to have some plugins in the ./plugin directory.
Every plugin is a .NET dll and should have the namespace "Plugin" and a class "MainClass" implementing the IPlugin interface defined in the main app.
The problem I have is that I don't know how I could share the same interface across the main app and every plugin *without* a `using` reference?

A part of the main app class:

```
        object oo = Assembly.LoadFile(path).CreateInstance("Plugin.MainClass");
        IPlugin pp = (IPlugin)oo; //Fails if I define the interface in the main app and the plugins
```

and a part of the first plugin:

```
namespace Plugin
{
    public class MainClass : IPlugin //I cannot reference the interface in the main app?
    {
       public string getName()
       {
          return "Plugin 1";
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct in that to use an interface (or class, struct etc...) you must reference that assembly. If you do not wish to have your plugins reference the main application (which makes sense) Why not add a new assembly for this purpose? Calling it 'framework' or 'util'.

E.G

> ```
> Framework Assembly
>  - IPlugin
>
> PluginOne Assembly (references Framework)
>  - PluginOne : IPlugin
>
> Main App Exe (references PluginOne & Framework assemblies)
> ```

Comment: But how can I reference the framework or util dll without `using` statements?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do that?! It is part of the language specification, a using statement disambiguates a type, qualifying it by its full namespace. It is like asking to write C# without braces {}!

Comment: As said, you don't have to avoid this using statement. It's part of the language.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I cant use it because the directory of the main app as well as the directory and the name of the plugins is not fixed. That means that sometimes the app is in "C:\\" while the plugins are in "C:\\plugins" and sometimes the main app is in "C:\\application\\" and the plugins are in "C:\\foo\\bar\\plugins"

Comment: "USING" has nothing to do with file locations - it has to do with ASSEMBLY references.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo Not cool or constructive. No one overreaches their ability. Who are we to say what his ability is.

Answer (score 3):

Just define the `IPlugin` interface in a separate assembly.

Also, you should totally be looking at MEF if you're not already: http://mef.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

You want a class library assembly that contains only the interfaces that **both** the main application and the plugins are built against.

Answer (score 3):

One point about this:

> Every plugin is a .NET dll and should have the namespace "Plugin" and a class "MainClass"

You cannot enforce the plug-in's namespace or class names unless you're the one writing them.

If you publish the interface (from a separate assembly as others have suggested), and I implement your interface, it doesn't matter if my Namespace is Plugin with class MainClass or the namespace is "TheEvilGreebo" and the class name is "IsGod".

As long as my "TheEvilGreebo.IsGod" class IMPLEMENTS your IPlugin properly, that's all that matters from your perspective as the interface designer.

Comment: Yes but in my documentation I'll write that every plugin *has* to implement the class with exactly the same name and namespace

Comment: But why? You cannot enforce it, you should not enforce it.

Comment: Your documentation will be wrong then.  It's not up to you to dictate to me how my code will look, EXCEPT for the part where the interface is involved.  The interface is a contract between classes/assemblies - and that's the ONLY thing I have to adhere to when working with what you write.

Comment: How can my app then know what the name of the class is that its going to cast to `IPlugin`?

Comment: Your app doesn't and won't.  What, exactly, do you imagine your application will do with the plugin I write?

Comment: Its going to take the MainClass (or whatever name you like) and cast it to `IPlugin` interface. The interface forces your class to have a method called `GetData()`. Thats all I want!

Comment: Ok - I get the idea but you're going about it the wrong way.  Your plugins need to register themselves with your main app in such a way that they tell the main app how to identify them (ie: their assembly name and class name) - and then your loadassembly can use the name they provide.  Once you load that assembly as "oo" (from your example) you can cast oo to IPlugin and call what you need.

Comment: yes but I cant cast them to IPlugin because my app is throwing InvalidCastException. I have to somehow use the same interface rather that just copying the interface definition into every plugin.

Comment: Yes, and thats why you put IPlugin in its own assembly, which your main app and which the plugins will need to reference.

Comment: That leads to my problem in the first place. Thus everything keeps moving around and there is no relative path from the app to any of its plugins/dependencies I cannot just create a reference in my VS project, because once my plugins folder resides deep in the system my app crashes saying that it could not find "util.dll"

Comment: I think you need to tell us what you are trying to do instead of giving us a technical solution and saying it doesn't work. Because I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve, except perhaps that you are heading in the wrong direction.